# mapping between python dictionaries and lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict =  {1: {'f1': 'name', 'f2': 'age', 'f3': 'class'}, 2: {'f1': 'company', 'f2': 'salary', 'f3': 'age', 'f4': 'class'}, 3: {'f1': 'Feature', 'f2': 'sum', 'f3': 'diff', 'f4': 'multiply', 'f5': 'div', 'f6': 'and', 'f7': 'or', 'f8': 'not', 'f9': 'dummy'}}

my_list =  [{3: {'sum': 'NONE', 'diff': 'yes', 'multiply': 'NONE', 'div': 'NONE', 'FEATURE': 'Maths', 'AND': 'NONE', 'OR': 'NONE', 'NOT': 'NONE', 'dummy': 'NONE'}}, {2: {'COMPANY': 'NONE', 'SALARY': 'Pass', 'AGE': 'NONE', 'CLASS': 'unknown'}}, {1: {'NAME': 'Pass', 'AGE': 'NONE', 'CLASS': '3'}}]
```

need output as mapping between my_dict to my_list in the following manner

```
new_level_dict_list=[{3: {'f1': 'Maths', 'f2': 'none', 'f3': 'yes', 'f4': 'NONE', 'f5': 'NONE', 'f6': 'NONE', 'f7': 'NONE', 'f8': 'NONE', 'f9': 'NONE'}}, {2: {'f1': 'NONE', 'f2': 'Pass', 'f3': 'NONE', 'f4': 'unknown'}}, {1: {'f1': 'Pass', 'f2': 'NONE', 'f3': '3'}}]
```

Code:

```
def function(my_dict, my_list):       
    # What should go here to get the required output
```

I tried below code to map two dictionaries but not with list and dictionary

```
def function(dict1,dict2)
        for key,value in dict1.iteritems():
           print key
           result[key] = dict2[value]
       print result

function(dict1, dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should get the job done:

```
# first transform the list to a dict
my_dict2 = {}
[my_dict2.update(key) for key in my_list]

# now search the old dict replace the key in question with the one from the new dict
for key in my_dict:
    for key2 in my_dict[key]:
        searchKey = my_dict[key][key2]
        if searchKey.upper() in my_dict2[key].keys():
            my_dict[key][key2] = my_dict2[key][searchKey.upper()]
        else:
            my_dict[key][key2] = my_dict2[key][searchKey]
print my_dict
```

Beaware that you have both lowercase and uppercase keys in your dict, which you should normalize before.

Answer (score 0):

For easier iteration I first converted `my_list` to `my_dict2` so it would be easier to iterate on both together. I can do it so since every dict in `my_list` have only one key

```
my_dict2 = {d.keys()[0]: d.values()[0] for d in my_list}
```

The next step is to iterate over those dictionaries and to create the combined element using `dict` which unites the items from both values -

```
new_level_dict_list = []
for key in set(my_dict.keys()).union(my_dict2):
    val1 = my_dict.get(key, {})
    val2 = my_dict2.get(key, {})
    val = dict(val1.items() + val2.items())
    new_level_dict_list.append({key : dict(val1.items() + val2.items())})
```